# How to handle lots of tables (5.000) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, rails-activerecord, rails-routing

I have a Ruby on Rails application running Ruby 2 and Rails 4. The main purpose of the application is to import and view data from other databases, which it does pretty well. To accomplish this I create MVCs and routes for every imported table. But I've come across a little performance problem and want to know if there is a way to optimize it.

As example I import 5.000 tables into my application. For every table I need to define a route, a model, a controller and a view. I need to display, sort, search and export all or selected objects from a table.

My workflow right now is that I have Sidekiq running in background scaffolding all those MVCs for every table and then creating a routes file (of which I have several) with 5.000 routes for those.

The main problem is that having 25.000 files and a routes file with 20.000 lines of code isn't really helpful in keeping the application simple and fast.

Another way I came up with was to have one dynamic MVC and a controller method for each table and get the data via:
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection`

This would slim everything a little bit down having less files, less controllers and less models, but I would still have a lot of routes and views. And also I haven't found a solution to do searching, sorting and exporting like I do it right now.

So, I would simply like to know, what solutions you have for such an hunge amount of tables. Anything tips, help and outside-the-box-thinking is really appreciated!

**Update to clarfiy things:**

Having 5.000 tables is neccessary. My application is basically a way to migrate old data from databases, files or whatever and store it in my application and the connected MySQL database. I'm talking here about millions of records, tenthousands of fields and just loads and loads of data that I cannot merge together or simplify, because I did not create the data in the first place, but I have to store it!

Comment: It sounds like there is a significant problem with your DB structure.

Comment: `...having 25.000 files and a routes file with 20.000 lines of code isn't really helpful in keeping the application simple and fast.` - and having 5000 tables in your application is simple/fast?

Comment: I would love to see this app in action!

Comment: Having 5.000 tables is neccessary. My application is basically a way to migrate old data from databases, files or whatever and store it in my application and the connected MySQL database. I'm talking here about millions of records, tenthousands of fields and just loads and loads of data that I cannot merge together or simplify, because I did not create the data in the first place, but I have to store it!

Comment: Do you need the MVC stack for each table all the time or is only one used at once? I was thinking if the MVC parts are always the same you could just have a base class with all the functionality and use tell it to use a different table as the data source.

Comment: @Kris: The MVC with its basic functionality is always the same. I only adjust it to the name and fields the selected table has. The same goes for the route. Basically one dynamic route would be enough. But especially in production where the model is cached, I don't see any possibility for an MVC which is dynamic enough to adjust to the different tables. But if you have a way of doing this that would be great and I would really really appreciate it!

Comment: Please dont use ruby on rails for this.. Try only Ruby...

Answer (score 0):

There's a few comments so to fork discussion I'm adding an answer.

My question is - do you really need Rails for that? From what you write the app is used only to display (and migrate?) data between databases. Wouldn't some tool like MySQL Admin, etc. bo sufficient here?

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna explain a little bit more about what I'm doing. You're correct with half of the application. I migrate, import and view data from different sources and types. But besides viewing them I also create new MVCs combining, linking and merging the original data. Which can all be done with a web-interface by the user. By now the application has grown quite complex and there is no possible away I could do this without Rails, but thanks for taking your time in reading and answering my problem and question. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Ok, that quite changes project definition. I was about to suggest an app that could have similiar functionality as phpmyadmin, but it makes no sense.

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind - stop using activerecord. As much as AR is a nice feature to ease/speed up development in most cases, in your's it might be faster to have model information "hard coded" in ORM, but I don't know if any such solutions exist for Ruby.